# extraer los keys que tienen el mismo valor dentro de un objeto

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando separar los los keys que tienen el mismo valor dentro de un objeto

```
{'0':3, '1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, '5':0, '6':6, '7':3, '8':1, '9':1}
```

deveria como resultado los keys con valor 0 serian {1,2,3,5}, con valor 1 serian {4,8,9} con valor 3 seria {7} y con valor 6 serian {6}, si ubieren keys con otros valores igualmente tendrian el mismo analisis

```
{ '1':0 ,'2':0, '3':0, '5':0 } { '4':1 ,'8':1, '9':1} { '7':3 } { '6':6 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes llenar un objeto donde cada propiedad sea uno de valores de tu objeto, cuyo valor -de la propiedad- sería un arreglo de índices; accediendo a los valores con la  *Notación por corchetes*.

```js
var a = {'0':3, '1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, '5':0, '6':6, '7':3, '8':1, '9':1}
var valores = {}
Object.keys(a).forEach( 
   function(k){
      if( !(a[k] in valores) ) // Inicializa la propiedad si aún no esta definida
         valores[a[k]] = []
      valores[a[k]].push(k)
   }
)
console.log("resultado:",valores)
```

Resultado:

```
{ 0: ['1','2','3','5']
, 1: ['4','8','9']
, 3: ['0','7']
, 6: ['6']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué te parece si en lugar de almacenarlos en un objeto, mejor los almacenas en un array como valor de cada clave, donde cada clave vendría siendo un valor encontrado?

Si es así, es muy sencillo con `Objects`, un foreach, y agrupando:

```js
const nums = {'0':3, '1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, '5':0, '6':6, '7':3, '8':1, '9':1}
var grouped = {}

for ([key, value] of Object.entries(nums)) {
  if (!(value in grouped)) grouped[value] = []
  grouped[value].push(key) 
}

console.log(grouped)
```